# Electron desktop capture multi-monitor view resolution too small

Tags: javascript, electron, webrtc, chromium, getusermedia

I have an electron application that is successfully screensharing the desktop via WebRTC.

Unfortunately, when the screen-shared machine has multiple monitors, the call to getUserMedia which generates the stream seems to shrink the overall resolution of the stream into a single screens worth of data.

So for example a machine has 3 monitors running 1920x1080 resolution each. The resulting desktop stream is for some reason itself 1920x1080, with 3 desktop screens squashed into it. The resulting resolution is unreadable at the destination.

I've been unable to find a way around this. Any ideas?

For reference I open the stream as per the documentation at https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/desktop-capturer:

```
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  audio: {
    mandatory: {
      chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
    }
  },
  video: {
    mandatory: {
      chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
    }
  }
})
```

Setting various widths/minWidths etc in the constraints appear to be ignored. The solution works fine except for this one issue - how do I increase the stream resolution to make all desktop screens readable on the destination? I don't care about frame rate.

This doesn't appear to be an issue with WebRTC itself - the resolution is too low within the stream before I even try addings its tracks to WebRTC.

Comment: Should have noted - I'm only looking for a Windows solution for this.

Comment: Does https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/getdisplaymedia/ offer three separate screens on the same machine? This might be a capturer limitation

Comment: Yes it shows Screen 1, 2, 3 as options.

Comment: I would note that the linked code you reference uses getDisplayMedia() while electron documentation uses getUserMedia().

Comment: electron still uses an older version of the API (that makes slightly more sense since it avoids some of the privacy concerns of the web version), the capturer will be the same (depending on the version, Chrome recently switched to a different capture API on Windows)

Comment: Appreciate the time you took to look at this so many thanks. Any suggestions as to approaches/alternatives I should look into to resolve this or do you think I may be stuck?

Comment: last thing to try would be reproducing it in the browser running --disable-features=AllowWgcDesktopCapture (which would suggest the new capturer supports it) and then checking the Electron status of that (adding --enable-features=... might work but still be in an unfinished state)